# I'm having trouble adding images to a question using a Mac

Tags: bug, status-completed

I notice that the add-image component dialogue has changed since I last asked a question. I now cannot upload an image using my Mac in either Chrome or Safari, using either an image from my computer or from the web. Is anyone else having this problem?

Here is the post in question . . .

[Why are the pads different for THT / SMT components in Eagle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59730/why-are-the-pads-different-for-tht-smt-pads-in-eagle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't you or your mac; sorry, we broke something. Fixed already and deploying ASAP (as in: the next few minutes).

See also: [Adding a picture from the web doesn't work on Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170029/adding-a-picture-from-the-web-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome)